# How should OpenAI environments (gyms) use env.seed(0)?

Tags: random, random-seed, openai-gym

I've created a very simple OpenAI gym ([`banana-gym`](https://github.com/MartinThoma/banana-gym)) and wonder if / how I should implement `env.seed(0)`.

See https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/250#issuecomment-234126816 for example.

Answer (score 4):

In a recent [merge](https://github.com/openai/gym/pull/836), the developers of OpenAI gym changed the behavior of `env.seed()` to not call the method `env._seed()` anymore. Instead the method now just issues a warning and returns. I think if you want to use this method to set the seed of your environment, you should just overwrite it now.

Answer (score 3):

env.seed(seed) works like a charm. The key is to  seed the env not just at the beginning, but EVERY time the reset() function is called. Since we invariably end up playing multiple games during training this seeding function should be inside one of the loops and will be executed multiple times. Possibly this is the reason why it is deprecated now in favor of env.reset(seed=seed)

Of course needless to say, if you are using randomness in the agent, you need to seed that as well. In that case, seeding once at the start of the training would be fine. You may want to seed the NN framework as well.. A typical seeding function (Pytorch) would be:

```
def seed_everything(seed):
    random.seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
    torch.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
    env.seed(seed)

##One call at beginning is enough
seed_everything(SEED)
```

Howver remember to call env.seed every time you reset the env:

```
curr_state = env.reset()
env.seed(SEED)
```

or simply use the new API: env.reset(seed=seed)

BUT - While this determinism may be used in early training to debug your code, it is recommended not to use the the same(ie env.seed(SEED)) in your final training. This is because, by nature, the start position of the environment is supposed to be random and your RL code is expected to function considering that randomness. If you make your start position deterministic then your model will not perform well in the live environment

Comment: I am a little confused. If I call env.reset(seed) everytime I reset my environment during training, would it mean that every time if my agent was to take the same actions the environment would play out the same scenario over and over again ? I want seed for every environment stochasticity to be the same but don't want the same environment to play out if I were to give the same actions during consecutive episodes.

Answer (score 2):

The docstring of the `env.seed()` function (which can be found in [this file](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/core.py)) provides the following documentation on what the function should be implemented to do:

```
Sets the seed for this env's random number generator(s).

    Note:
        Some environments use multiple pseudorandom number generators.
        We want to capture all such seeds used in order to ensure that
        there aren't accidental correlations between multiple generators.
    Returns:
        list<bigint>: Returns the list of seeds used in this env's random
          number generators. The first value in the list should be the
          "main" seed, or the value which a reproducer should pass to
          'seed'. Often, the main seed equals the provided 'seed', but
          this won't be true if seed=None, for example.
```

Note that, unlike what the documentation and the comments in the issue you linked to seem to imply, it doesn't seem (to me) like `env.seed()` is supposed to be overridden by custom environments. `env.seed()` has a very simple implementation, where it only calls and returns the return value of `env._seed()`, and it seems to me like *that* is the function which should be overridden by custom environments.

For example, OpenAI gym's [atari environments](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/atari/atari_env.py) have a custom `_seed()` implementation which sets the seed used internally by the (`C++`-based) Arcade Learning Environment.

Since you have a `random.random()` call in [your custom environment](https://github.com/MartinThoma/banana-gym/blob/master/gym_banana/envs/banana_env.py), you should probably implement `_seed()` to call `random.seed()`. In that way, users of your environments can reproduce experiments by making sure to call `seed()` on your environment with the same argument.

**Note:** Messing around with the global random seed like this may be unexpected though, it may be better to create a dedicated random object when your environment gets initialized, seed that object, and make sure to always obtain your random numbers if you need them in the environment from that object.